# HTML table data starting from CENTER instead of TOP

Tags: html, css

I have a `HTML` table whose data is coming from the database. Currently the data is getting filled from the center instead of top. Like below:-

[image: Image desc]

Have a look at the below HTML

```
<table style="width: 100%; height: 550px; text-align: center" border="1" runat="server"
    id="tbl1Details">
    <colgroup>
        <col width="5%" />
        <col width="45%" />
    </colgroup>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">
            <asp:Label ID="lblpltfrm_Number" runat="server" Style="height: 20px;"></asp:Label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center" style="height: 20px;">
            SR.
        </td>
        <td align="center" style="height: 20px;">
            Stop
        </td>
        <td align="center" style="height: 20px;">
            Time
        </td>
        <td align="center" style="height: 20px;">
            Status
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="tTime" runat="server">
            <div id="list" runat="server" style="font-size: 25px;">
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <table style="width: 100%">
                <colgroup>
                    <col width="50%" />
                    <col width="50%" />
                </colgroup>
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: left">
                        <div id="dv_FromStop" style="font-size: 25px;" runat="server">
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: left">
                        <div id="Dv_ToStop" style="font-size: 25px;" runat="server">
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div id="dv_Time" style="font-size: 25px;" runat="server">
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div id="dv_status" style="font-size: 25px;" runat="server">
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: any downvote should have a reasonable comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following CSS:

```css
table td {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

Or in HTML, use either:

```
<td valign="top">
<td style="vertical-align: top;">
```

The second one is preferred because, `valign` is deprecated.

Comment: I have more than one table, so `ID` i cant use. and inline css i dont prefer

Comment: @coder I gave `ID` because, it targets all the `td`s. It shouldn't be like that.

Comment: tried like this `vertical-align: top;
            padding: 0;` but not working

Answer (score 0):

Use `vertical-align`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align.

In CSS:

```
td { vertical-align: top; }
```

In HTML:

```
<td valign="top">...</td>
```

Comment: Add notes rather only the solution as code on how this solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to use vertical alignment.

css:

```
td { vertical-align:top; }
```